# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column when creating a new column conditionally, using a map of UDFs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a data of device IDs with startTime and some feature vectors, which needs to be merged based on `hour` or `weekday_hour`. The sample data is as follows:

```
+-----+-------------------+--------------------+
|hh_id|          startTime|                hash|
+-----+-------------------+--------------------+
|dev01|2016-10-10 00:01:04|(1048576,[121964,...|
|dev02|2016-10-10 00:17:45|(1048576,[121964,...|
|dev01|2016-10-10 00:18:01|(1048576,[121964,...|
|dev10|2016-10-10 00:19:48|(1048576,[121964,...|
|dev05|2016-10-10 00:20:00|(1048576,[121964,...|
|dev08|2016-10-10 00:45:13|(1048576,[121964,...|
|dev05|2016-10-10 00:56:25|(1048576,[121964,...|
```

The features are basically SparseVectors, which are merged by a custom function. When I try to create a **key** column in the following way:

```
val columnMap = Map("hour" -> hour($"startTime"), "weekday_hour" -> getWeekdayHourUDF($"startTime"))
val grouping = "hour"
val newDF = oldDF.withColumn("dt_key", columnMap(grouping))
```

I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException`. The complete stack trace is below:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: hour(startTime))
    - field (class: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3, name: value1, type: class java.lang.Object)
    - object (class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3, Map(hour -> hour(startTime), weekday_hour -> UDF(startTime), none -> 0))
    - field (class: linef03f4aaf3a1c4f109fce271f7b5b1e30104.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: groupingColumnMap, type: interface scala.collection.immutable.Map)
    - object (class linef03f4aaf3a1c4f109fce271f7b5b1e30104.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, linef03f4aaf3a1c4f109fce271f7b5b1e30104.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@4f1f9a63)
    - field (class: linef03f4aaf3a1c4f109fce271f7b5b1e30104.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, name: $iw, type: class linef03f4aaf3a1c4f109fce271f7b5b1e30104.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw)
    - object (class linef03f4aaf3a1c4f109fce271f7b5b1e30104.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw, linef03f4aaf3a1c4f109fce271f7b5b1e30104.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw@207d6d1e)
```

But when I try to execute the same logic without creating columns explicitly, using if-else, I don't face any such errors.

```
val newDF = if(groupingKey == "hour") {
  oldDF.withColumn("dt_key", hour($"startTime")
} else {
  oldDF.withColumn("dt_key", getWeekdayHourUDF($"startTime")
}
```

It will be really convinient to do it using the Map-way, as there might be more type of key extraction methods. Please help me in figuring out why this issue is being caused.

Comment: you should write a udf function to create the maps

Comment: @RameshMaharjan You mean, I need to create a UDF which contains a map of the functions to be applied rather than creating a map of UDFs?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in Spark 1.6 or Spark 2.2. Are you sure theres no problem with the UDF? What is the type of `columnMap`? it should be `Map[String, Column]`.

Comment: @philantrovert Yes, the type of the `columnMap` is `scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,org.apache.spark.sql.Column]`. I don't think there is a problem with the UDF, but here is code for it. 
    
`val localDateTime = ts.toLocalDateTime` and then `(localDateTime.getDayOfWeek.getValue - 1)*24 + localDateTime.getHour`


`val getWeekdayHourUDF = udf(getWeekdayHour _)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**when inbuilt function**

You can achieve your requirement by using a `when` inbuilt function as

```
val groupingKey = //"hour" or "weekday_hour"
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("dt_key", 
     when(lit(groupingKey) === "hour", hour($"startTime"))
     .when(lit(groupingKey) === "weekday_hour", getWeekdayHourUDF($"startTime"))
     .otherwise(lit(0)))).show(false)
```

**udf function**

Alternatively you can create a `udf` function *to create the map column* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def mapUdf = udf((hour: Int, weekdayhour: Int, groupingKey: String) => 
      if(groupByKey.equalsIgnoreCase("hour")) hour 
      else if(groupByKey.equalsIgnoreCase("weekday_hour")) weekdayhour 
      else 0)
```

And use it as

```
val newDF = oldDF.withColumn("dt_key",
                  mapUdf(hour($"startTime"), 
                         getWeekdayHourUDF($"startTime"),
                         lit(groupingKey)))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding regarding the question. The dataframe has the `startTime` column and the `dt_key` column is dervied conditionally on the value of `groupingKey` whose value can be `hour` or `weekday_hour`. Finally, I don't need a map of columns, I just need a single column as the result.

Comment: what is groupingKey then? is it another column?

Comment: No, it's just a String variable with values `"hour"` or `"weekday_hour"`. It defines the type of grouping to be done on the whole data. The other function `hour` that I'm referring to is the `spark.sql.functions.hour`, which extracts the hour from the timestamp.

Comment: Ah! I see. You've transferred the if-else inside the `mapUDF`. But the problem is, I can't use the native functions provided by Spark in this method. :( I'm hoping there is some other easier way to do this. I tried using `transient` keyword for the `columnMap`, but even that doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated the answer again :) Hope this time I answered it as you wanted

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I will accept your answer for now, but it seems much simpler if I do it using if-else as I've mentioned at the end of the question. I mainly wanted to know the reason why my initial method wasn't working.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a little late, but I am at Spark 2.4.6 and couldn't reproduce the issue. I'm guessing the code calls `columnMap` for multiple keys. It helps if you provide an easily reproducible example, including data (1-row dataset is enough). However, as the stack trace says, the `Column` class is indeed not `Serializable`, and I'll try to elaborate according to my current understanding.

TLDR; One easy way to circumvent that is to turn `val`s into `def`s.

---

I believe it's already clear why expressing the same thing with `when` cases or UDFs works.

**First attempt**: The reason why something like that may not work is because (a) the `Column` class is not serializable (which I believe to be a conscious design choice given its intended role within the Spark API), and (b) there is nothing in the expression

```scala
oldDF.withColumn("dt_key", columnMap(grouping))
```

that tells Spark what will be the actual concrete `Column` for the second parameter of `withColumn`, which means that the concrete `Map[String, Column]` object will need to be sent over the network to executors, when an exception like that would be raised.

**Second attempt**: The reason why the second attempt works is because the same decision regarding this `groupingKey` parameter required to define the `DataFrame` can happen entirely on the driver.

---

It helps to think about Spark code using the `DataFrame` API as a query builder, or something holding an execution plan, and not the data itself. Once you call an action on it (`write`, `show`, `count` etc), Spark generates code that sends tasks to executors. At that moment, all information needed to materialize the `DataFrame`/`Dataset` must be either already properly encoded in the query plan or needs to be serializable so that it can be sent over the network.

`def` usually solves this kind of issue because

```scala
def columnMap: Map[String, Column] = Map("a" -> hour($"startTime"), "weekday_hour" -> UDF($"startTime"))
```

is not the concrete `Map` object itself but something that *creates* a new `Map[String, Column]` every time it is called, say at each executor that happens to take a task that involving this `Map`.

[This](https://www.toptal.com/scala/scala-bytecode-and-the-jvm) and [this](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book-diffs-val-def-scala-functions/) seem like good resources on the topic. I confess I get why using a `Function` like

```scala
val columnMap = () => Map("a" -> hour($"startTime"), "b" -> UDF($"startTime"))
```

and then `columnMap()("a")` would work, since the de-compiled byte code shows that `scala.Function`s are defined as concrete instances of `Serializable`, but I do not get why `def` works since that doesn't look to be the case for them. Anyways, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Changing `val` to `def` did it for me!